# Bounded Linear Combination of Real Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, linear-transformations

Let us consider a set of $N$ vectors, $\mathbf{h}_1, \mathbf{h}_2, \cdots, \mathbf{h}_N$, such that $\mathbf{h}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{M}$, $\forall i$, with $M < N$.

Let us also consider the space $\mathcal{X}$ obtained from bounded linear combinations of such vectors, *i.e.*

$$\mathcal{X} = \{\mathbf{x} \;|\; \mathbf{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i\mathbf{h}_i, a_i \in [-A,A], \forall i\}$$
For $M=2$, I've performed some numerical simulations and I've observed that $\mathcal{X}$ corresponds to a polygon, whose sides are parallel to $\mathbf{h}_i$.

Also, the vertices of such a polygon correspond to some of the linear combinations of $\mathbf{h}_i$ made with $|a_i| = A$, $i=1, 2, ..., N$, *i.e., * the vertices are obtained when the coefficients $a_i$ attain their maximum absolute values, but not every combination made with such coefficients leads to a vertex.

**Question: ** Is it possible to characterize $\mathcal{X}$ for higher values of $M$? Is there any material about bounded linear combinations of vectors?

Comment: It's the convex hull of the points you identified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But one thing that I've not completely understood is why the sides of the convex hull are parallel to $h_i$. Do you know how can I check this fact?